# Problems animating clothes

Tags: animation, armature, cloth-simulation

So I'm trying to animate a sort of cloth fan but I can´t don´t really know how to do it.

[image: Model and armature]

I've created an armature for the object and asigned it to the sticks. The problem is that I don´t know how to pin the cloth to each bone of the armature so that it animates properly. If I weight paint has I would do for a character, in the cloth simulation panel I can only pin it to 1 bone and if I create a vertex group with te vertex over the sticks the cloth simulation doesn´t animate properly, it becomes kind of rigid.

Any help?

Thanks.

Update: So I asigned a part of the cloth to each bone like that:
[image: Weight for 1st bone]

And created a vertex group where I pinned my clothing:
 [image: ClothPinning]

The problem now is that when I animate, the cloth moves "slower" than the sticks, it doesn´t move like bone is moving:
[image: Jesus]

Edit: These are my cloth settings. The pinning group *"cloth"* is the one mentioned before.
[image]
I activated *Dynamic mesh* thinking that it would solve it (you know, it's a mesh that's moving, silly me), bu it didn´t.

Comment: please show the settings for the cloth modifier

Comment: What it looks like to me, here, is conflicting bone weights. Just a guess, but are you sure no other bone is influencing the same area? Are you sure that the ones that should be, are? The second "patch" of your fan should also be sensitive to the far bone to the right, not only the immediately adjacent one.